# HTMLメールのデコード処理を実施したい

Tags: python, python3, html, gmail

やりたいこと：
gmailのHTMLメールを取得してメールと同じ日本語に変換したいです。

コード：

```
import imaplib,email
from email.message import Message
from email.header import Header
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import imaplib, re, email, six, dateutil.parser
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import base64

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
mail.login('hogehoge@gmail.com','test123')
mail.select("inbox")

#特定のメールUNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
term = u"件名".encode("utf-8")
mail.literal = term
type,data=mail.search("utf-8", "UNSEEN SUBJECT")

for i in data[0].split():   #data分繰り返す
    ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')    #メールの情報を取得
    ms=email.message_from_string(x[0][1].decode('utf-8'))    #パースして取得

    #差出人を取得
    ad=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('From'))
    ms_code=ad[0][1]
    if(ms_code!=None):
        address=ad[0][0].decode(ms_code)
        address+=ad[1][0].decode(ms_code)
    else:
        address=ad[0][0]

    #件名を取得
    msg_subject = email.header.decode_header(ms.get('Subject'))[0][0]
    print(msg_subject)

    #本文を取得
    maintext=ms.get_payload()

    #body文字コードを元に戻すbase64
    body_decode=(base64.b64decode(maintext).decode())
```

メール取得の一部：

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.= w
```

この後もHTML形式の表示が続きます

エラー内容：

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

色々調べたのですが、文字コードが間違っているということでしょうか。

Comment: 以前の質問でもエラーメッセージは全てで1行だったようですが、動作環境によるのかもしれません。google apps script?とかではなくローカルなPC環境でのPythonインタプリタで実行すると全文が表示されると思われます。そうして表示されたエラーメッセージを略さず全て提示してください。

Comment: この辺の記事が何か参考になるかもしれませんね。[Read email in python 3.7 using imaplib with HTML body and attachments in the email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53444318/9014308), [email.message_from_string() and imaplib adding '<' '>'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28939011/9014308), [imaplib と email ライブラリーを使ったメールの処理](https://www.shido.info/py/python_imap.html), [Python3でGmailからメール取得とラベル付け](https://qiita.com/stkdev/items/a44976fb81ae90a66381), [Pythonでメール受信; imaplibのサンプルコード](https://qiita.com/takey/items/1498af9e1113eeb7bb21)